# How to create a menu console loop?

Tags: java

I have to create a menu for the user to select from and I need it to loop when the user inputs the incorrect option. The code that I have so far; it will either loop continually or when I run the program it, gives me the outputs for all the selections instead of for the one I specifically entered. The loop I have is a do / while loop with a switch statement. I'll paste what I've tried below. I just need to know if my code for the loop is correct and if not how do I fix it? If any clarifications are needed, just ask. I apologize if I sound really lazy or stupid, I just want to be able to understand this and at times, I just don't, so just look for a little extra help.

```
 do
{

int selection = 0;


System.out.println("Please choose one of the following to determine whether you are a new or existing cutomer:");
System.out.println("[1]- Existing Customer");
System.out.println("[2] - New Customer");

System.out.println("Insert selection:");


switch (selection)
{
case 1:
System.out.println("Welcome Back" + userName);
break;

case 2:
System.out.println("Hello, I see you are a new customer,");
System.out.println("let's get your account setup!");
break;

case 3:
default: System.out.println("That is not a vaild. Please select from one of the following options.");
break;
}
while (selection !=3);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
         String[] options = new String[]{
           "Existing Customer",
           "New Customer"
         };   

        int selection = 0;

        do{
            System.out.println("Please choose one of the following to determine whether you are a new or existing customer");
            for (int i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
                System.out.printf("[%s] - %s%n",i+1, options[i]);
            }
            String input = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
            try{
                selection = Integer.parseInt(input);
            }catch(NumberFormatException e){
                System.out.println("That is not a vaild. Please select from one of the following options.");
                selection = 0;
            }
        }while(selection <= 0 || selection > options.length);

        switch(selection){
            case 1:
                System.out.println("Welcome Back");
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("Hello, I see you are a new customer,");
                System.out.println("let's get your account setup!");
                break;
        }
```

Comment: Thank you! Can I ask why you added the "String [ ] options = new String [ ]